# Rails: Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm on a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 machine, Ruby 2.2.3 installed with RVM, and I'm trying to run a Rails 4.2 application.

After `rails s` command I get:

```
davide@davidell:~/app/app-backend$ rails s
Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
Please use a String or nil.
An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app", "/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:338:in `rescue in load': Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler (undefined method `getbyte' for false:FalseClass), ActiveSupport::Multibyte is unusable (IOError)
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:335:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:326:in `codepoints'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:147:in `block in decompose'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:136:in `each'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:136:in `inject'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:136:in `decompose'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:270:in `normalize'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb:62:in `transliterate'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb:83:in `parameterize'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:168:in `parameterize'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/scope.rb:35:in `initialize'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/resource/scopes.rb:34:in `new'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/resource/scopes.rb:34:in `scope'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/resource_dsl.rb:22:in `scope'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/app/admin/venue.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:15:in `run_registration_block'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:223:in `parse_registration_block'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:48:in `register'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:151:in `register'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin.rb:75:in `register'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/app/admin/venue.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:209:in `block in load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/error.rb:41:in `capture'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:209:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:201:in `block in load!'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:201:in `each'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:201:in `load!'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin/application.rb:223:in `routes'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config/routes.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `block in constraints'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `constraints'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config/routes.rb:316:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config.ru:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@app/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/davide/app/app-backend/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

After several `rails s` tries, it works, but it's a totally random number of trials. If I stop the application, the same error occurs, and after several other tries, it works. So random.

Now I got:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem ?

Comment: I actually got back to Ubuntu 16.04, since I got too many issue with 17.10. So far I had no time to move to 18.04