# Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler in Rails Admin (1.2.0)

Tags: mongodb, unicode, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I want to upgrade rails 3 to rails 5. There I am using mongodb as database. I am using rails admin 1.2.0. I am using jruby-9.1.7.0. I am rails api only app. My application gems are given below.

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'awesome_print', '~> 1.8.0'
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', :branch => 'master', :ref => "463351922fdafb96c50ba2496c7d0adaa3223283"
gem "doorkeeper-mongodb", github: "doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-mongodb"
gem 'cancan', github: 'DevAVIJIT7/cancan', :branch => 'master', :ref => "aa3729bd79d92a993c5186f983eccd2fd496c2d3"
gem 'puma','~> 3.11.0'
gem 'mongoid', '6.2.1'
gem 'mongoid-tree', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.2'
```

In my routes rails admin mount path and initializer file look like

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'


RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  RAILS_ADMIN_BASE_PATH = 'godview' 

  config.main_app_name = Proc.new do |controller| 
    [ "Admin", "#{controller.params[:action].try(:titleize)}" ] 
  end

  config.authenticate_with do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Login required') do |username, password|
      user = User.where(username: username).first
      if user && user.valid_password?(password) && user.role_names.include?("Super Admin")
        user
      else
        nil
      end  
    end
  end
end
```

when I run http://localhost:3000/admin on browser I am getting error.
[image]

In console I am getting

```
Started GET "/godview" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 at 2018-01-15 14:54:12 

+0530
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 263ms



IOError (Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler (undefined method 

`call' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  caller), ActiveSupport::Multibyte is unusable):
```

I went through the link [Rails: Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870310/rails-couldnt-load-the-unicode-tables-for-utf8handler) But didn't get any response.

*note : I am using /admin as /godview in my app.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem?

Comment: No not yet. are you using rails_admin?@Shiko

Comment: we solved it, it seems problem with UTF8 and docker.

Comment: But I wasn't using docker. But still can you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Docker on CentOS for our rails projects, and we got this error recently, we fixed it by explicitly specifying the `C.UTF8` encoding in the docker file as below:

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

**Encoding**
By default, Ruby inherits the locale of the environment in which it is run. For most users running Ruby on their desktop systems, that means it's likely using some variation of *.UTF-8 (en_US.UTF-8, etc). In Docker, however, the default locale is C, which can have unexpected results. If your application needs to interact with UTF-8, it is recommended that you explicitly adjust the locale of your image/container via -e LANG=C.UTF-8 or ENV LANG C.UTF-8

**References:**
https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/
https://oncletom.io/2015/docker-encoding/